Continuity and infinite products of topological spaces
Quickly scanning through an old final exam for a previous iteration of an analysis class I am interested in taking, I encountered the following problem: Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $\{Y_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be a possibly uncountable family of topological spaces.  For each $\alpha \in I$, suppose there is given a function $f_\alpha : X \to Y_\alpha$.  Let $F: X \to \prod_{\alpha \in I}Y_\alpha$ send $x \in X$ to the tuple $(f_\alpha(x))_{\alpha \in I}$.  Prove that $F$ is continuous if and only if $f_\alpha$ is continuous for every $\alpha \in I$.
The document from which this is taken I looked at without any context.  It may be that some particular intended meaning was ascribed to the notation above.  But isolated from any such context, it seems to me that this challenge is ill-posed, because the validity of the statement in bold depends I think on the topology of the product $\prod_{\alpha \in I}Y_\alpha$, right?  If given the box topology, the statement seems to be just not true.  A counterexample that comes to mind:
Let $X$ be the real line equipped with the Euclidean topology.  For each $\alpha \in (0, 1/2]$, say, let $$I_\alpha = [1 - \alpha, 1 + \alpha].$$ For each $I_\alpha$ so defined, define a function $f_\alpha$ that assumes a value of $1$ throughout $I_\alpha$ but then smoothly descends very sharply to $0$ outside of it.  Letting each $Y_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0, 1/2]$ be a copy of $X$, the $f_\alpha$ are individually continuous but seem to yield an $F$ which isn't.
To see this, let $V = \prod_{\alpha \in (0, 1/2]}(1 - \alpha, 1 + \alpha)$.  This contains $F(1)$, and is evidently an open set in the box topology.  Now, for $U$ any open set containing $1$, let $0 < \epsilon \ll 1/2$ be small enough that the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $1$ lies entirely within $U$.  But then the image of this ball under $f_{\epsilon/2}$ contains $0$ (I am assuming that the graphs of the $f_\alpha$ are sufficiently steep), which lies outside the $\epsilon/2$-th component of $V$.  This implies that $F(U) \not\subset V$. In particular, $F$ is discontinuous at $1$.
I was just hoping to check (a) whether I'm right in believing that the statement in question is not true in general and (b) whether the construction sketched above is a valid counterexample.  Thanks in advance.
Edit: originally I said "product topology" instead of "box topology"; I am so sorry for the confusion.


your math is correct,
as a standard convention, $\prod X_i$, with no further notation, gets the product topology,
although for that matter, as a standard convention, the definition of $\prod X_i$ is the one in terms of the statement about maps into it being a bunch of maps into the factors, which you are trying to prove


You should use the product topology on the product. Then the claim is correct. Indeed, the fact this claim is correct is more or less why we define the product topology the way we do: we want continuous functions into the product to be “exactly the same thing as” a family of continuous functions to the factors

@hunter Thank you so much for the sanity check on the example I proposed above and for the clarifying remarks - super helpful.

It is well-known that the product topology is the unique topology on $\prod_{\alpha \in I} Y_\alpha$ (where $I$ is any finite or infinite index set) such that the following is satisfied:

$F$ is continuous if and only if $f_\alpha$ is continuous for every $\alpha \in I$.

Here $F = F_{(f_\alpha)}$ is defined based on the given $f_\alpha$. However, normally one uses the following equivalent formulation:

A given function $f : X \to \prod_{\alpha \in I} Y_\alpha$ is continuous if and only if $\pi_\alpha \circ f$ is continuous for every $\alpha \in I$ (where the $\pi_\alpha : \prod_{\alpha \in I} Y_\alpha \to Y_\alpha$ are the projections).

See If every function is continuous if and only if its projections are continuous, can we conclude the codomain has the product topology? for a proof that 2. uniquely characterizes the product topology.
Let us check that 1. and 2. are equivalent.

$\implies$ 2.:

Let $f_\alpha := \pi_\alpha \circ f$. Then $F_{(f_\alpha)} = f$. From 1. we know that $f$ is continuous iff all $f_\alpha = \pi_\alpha \circ f$ are continuous.

$\implies$ 1.:

By definition we have $f_\alpha = \pi_\alpha \circ F$. From 2. we know that $F$ is continuous iff all $f_\alpha$ are continuous.
Your counterexample showing that the box topology in general does not satisfy 1. is correct. However, you do not need to get very explicit. All you have to do is to find an example where the box topology is strictly finer than the product topology (of course it is always finer).

The box topology and the product topology agree for finite $I$. Thus counterexamples require infinite $I$.

More generally, if all but finitely many $Y_\alpha$ have the trivial topology, then the box topology and the product topology agree.


Now we get the following
Lemma.  The box topology is strictly finer than the product topology if and only if  infinitely many $Y_\alpha$ have a non-trivial open set (this requires in particular that $I$ is infinite).
Proof. A basis for the product topology is given by the sets $\prod_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha$ with non-empty open $U_\alpha \subset Y_\alpha$ such that all but finitely many $U_\alpha = Y_\alpha$. Now let $(V_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I}$ be a family of non-empty open subsets of $Y_\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha \subsetneqq Y_\alpha$ for infinitely many $\alpha \in I$. Then $V = \prod_{\alpha \in I} V_\alpha$ is open in the box topology, but clearly does not contain any basis element of the product topology. Hence $V$ is not open in the product topology.
